# Testng test for specific exception with message

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to test if a method throws a specific exception with it's message like this :

```
@DataProvider(name = "correctPairs")
public Object[][] expectedResultsTest() {
return new Object[][] {
 { null, new NullPointerException("Class cannot be null") },
};
}

@Test(dataProvider = "correctPairs")
public void ormDefinitionClassTest(final Class<?> value, final Throwable e) {
try {
    DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();
    databaseManager.findAll(value);
} catch (Throwable ex) {

    Assert.assertEquals(ex, e);    
}
```

But it fails with the exception :

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: expected [java.lang.NullPointerException: Class cannot be null] but found [java.lang.NullPointerException: Class cannot be null]
```

How can I make it check for equality of Exceptions ,by using @DataProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use catchThrowable method from AssertJ fluent assertions. This way you can check the exception in test body, like

```
Throwable t = catchThrowable(() -> databaseManager.findAll(value));
assertThat(t).isInstanceOf(e);
```

EDIT: The problem here can be that you assume that these two exception objects are equal, but they are not equal objects. What you could do is to assert their type and message separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies in the equality test.

```
Assert.assertEquals(new NullPointerException(), new NullPointerException());
```

Returns false because the instances of the two exceptions are not the same.
You must compare the classes, then the messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class A implements ThrowingRunnable{


        @Override
        public void run() throws AuthenticationFailedException{
            spy.processAuthenticationResponse(mockRequest, mockResponse, authenticationContext);
        }
    }
    assertThrows(AuthenticationFailedException.class,new A());
```